# reactive-kafka with default dispatcher?

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I'm working in a project with Kafka and Akka Streams using [reactive-kafka](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka) connector. We have found that reactive-kafka use it's own dispatcher (akka.kafka.default-dispatcher) but if, instance of that, we use the default akka dispatcher, all is faster (reactive-kafka dispatcher ~300 messages/s, default dispatcher ~1300 messages/s )

I wonder if to use the default dispatcher would be safe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

No, you should not use Akka's default dispatcher. As the underlying Kafka client uses blocking it could stop the whole actor system from functioning.

Instead, you may reconfigure the `akka.kafka.default-dispatcher` (eg. by adding `akka.kafka.default-dispatcher.thread-pool-executor.fixed-pool-size = 32` to your settings) or even better configure your own dispatcher and use it for the Alpakka Kafka connector consumers that need it.

See [Akka dispatchers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html) for how to configure a dispatcher.